# Typescript - Access property of class using it's string name

Tags: typescript, ionic2

I'm having this class:

```
import { SoapNotePage } from "../pages/forms/soap-note/soap-note";

export class FormMapper {
    public static SOAP_NOTE = SoapNotePage;
}
```

It is easy to access this property, see the following example:

```
open(item){
    if(item.id == 1){
       this.navCtrl.push(FormMapper.SOAP_NOTE, { patientId: 509070, formId: 75598 });
    }
}
```

But what I want is to access the "SOAP_NOTE" property by it's string name, kind of dynamically, for example like this:

```
this.navCtrl.push(FormMapper['SOAP_NOTE'], { patientId: 509070, formId: 75598 });
```

The reason  I'm asking this, is that the "item" paramater of the function "open(item)" may contain the property name of the FormMapper class.

Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: Not sure what the problem is, you can access static members using an indexer. `FormMapper['SOAP_NOTE']` should be valid in Typescript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this:

```
function open(item: keyof typeof FormMapper) {
    console.log(FormMapper[item]);  
}
```

That way you restrict `item` values to be keys of the `FormMapper` class, and the compiler won't complain.